# iPhone background notifications

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, background-process

I'm making an iPhone app. I can receive UDP messages using AsyncUdpSocket. I want the app running in background, and when receive a message, an UIAlertView is displaying to the user, and he can enter in the app, or ignore the alert.
Is it possible to detect a message when the app is running in background.

Do I need something to execute my code in this method?

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {    
}
```

I saw lot of tutorials, with timer, but I don't need timer to wake up my app. Also I read that's it's possible while playing music, tracking position or using VOIP.

Do I need to play a fake song to keep my app running? or to do something like that?

This app is for security, for example if someone is touching or moving your motorbike/computer/whatever else, your iPhone can alert you and prevents from stealing.

I read other threads similar but didn't find an answer.

Thank you guys for giving me tips, or any help /sample.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run in the background on a non-jailbroken phone without being in one of those three categories of app, and Apple’s really unlikely to approve your app if you use that facility for another purpose. UDP probably isn’t the best solution for this anyway—if your phone leaves the network that the other device (whatever it is) is on, it won’t receive the notification at all, whether or not it’s in the foreground. You’re probably a lot better off using the push notification API.

Comment: You **can** run apps in the background in a non-jailbroken iOS environment. Just not on all devices.

Comment: Please re-read my answer—beyond the first ten words, this time, if you don't mind. I acknowledged the three categories of apps—VoIP, location-monitoring, and music—that are **allowed** to run in the background by the terms of the App Store, i.e. the main method of app distribution on non-jailbroken devices. An app **can** misleadingly label itself as one of those, but (as I said before) it won’t make it through the review process.

Comment: I have to use UDP to communicate with a sensor, that sends me informations through this protocol. I can't use Push notifications, which requires a server to send notifications, I just want to use local notifications, on a special event, like receiving a message

Comment: I've got a feeling the UDP gets blocked on 3G so this will only work on Wi-Fi. I may be wrong but I read that somewhere I'm sure!

Comment: Also don't forget that you will need to give clear instructions to Apple about what you're connecting too and allow them to test that it works with the device (on submission). You may have to go down the MFI route.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect case to use Apple Push Notifications (APN). You app can register to receive the notifications and the phone will alert the user with any combination of badging, messages, or sounds. Sounds like you already have a server that is sending the UDP messages, so incorporating APN should be minimal. Especially if you use a third-party to send the push notification, such as Urban Airship. (I am not affiliated with them, but have used them on a large commercial project.)

By definition, local events are not triggered by receiving a message.